# Gettin wrong results

Tags: java

when i put in 10 packages i get the correct results but when i put in 58, i get the wrong results.

**My output:**

```
Enter the number of packages purchased: 58
Your total without discount: 5742.0
The discount is: 1148.4
The discounted total: 4593.6
```

**What it should have:**

```
Enter the number of packages purchased: 58
Your total without discount: 5742.0
The discount is: 2411.6
The discounted total: 3330.3
```

```
package pkg;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double packageCost = 99.00;
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of packages purchased: ");
        int askPackage = user_input.nextInt();
        double withoutDiscount = packageCost * askPackage;
        double firstDiscount = (packageCost * askPackage) - (withoutDiscount * .20);
        double secondDiscount = (packageCost * askPackage) - (withoutDiscount * .33);
        double thirdDiscount = (packageCost * askPackage) - (withoutDiscount * .42);
        double fourthDiscount = (packageCost * askPackage) - (withoutDiscount * .49);
        System.out.println("Your total without discount: $" + withoutDiscount);
        if (askPackage >= 10 || askPackage <= 19) {
            System.out.println("The discount is: $" + withoutDiscount * .20);
            System.out.println("The discounted total: $" + firstDiscount);
        } else if (askPackage >= 20 || askPackage <= 49) {
            System.out.println("The discount is: $" + withoutDiscount * .33);
            System.out.println("The discounted total: $" + secondDiscount);
        } else if (askPackage >= 50 || askPackage <= 99) {
            System.out.println("The discount is: $" + withoutDiscount * .42);
            System.out.println("The discounted total: $" + thirdDiscount);
        } else if (askPackage >= 100) {
            System.out.println("The discount is: $" + withoutDiscount * .49);
            System.out.println("The discounted total: $" + fourthDiscount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need the `&&` operator instead of `||` in your `if`s.

Comment: Please try to post better formatted code, code without all the distracting empty lines. I've fixed your code this time, but again in the future, please put in this effort yourself. Your efforts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AndrewLygin I believe your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @naXa, it looks like a simple typo that the author missed and it's very unlikely that making my comment the answer would help anyone. I think the question should be closed.

Comment: Indeed. I'm with @AndrewLygin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `&&` instead of `||` in your if else statements. All possible inputs are processed in your first condition `askPackage >= 10 || askPackage <= 19` . Thus only inputs which are between 10-19 will give you true outputs.

P.S. You can do discount assignments like that:

```
double firstDiscount = (withoutDiscount * .80);
```

Or better solution; create a common `discount` variable and assign it in your if-else statements.

Comment: What is wrong about my answer? I wrote the correction and got a down vote :)